# how to use an object in a function without knowing what the object is

Tags: python, function, object

I want to use an object even when I don't know the name of the object. I am trying to use a function where it compares two objects and see which one has the biggest number, but I want to be able to type the objects into the argument of the function and then the function does the comparison, so I don't have to keep repeating the same code over and over again. The issue is that I don't know how to have an argument in a function say what object to compare.

```
 class tester:
  myVar = None

  def __init__(self, myVar):
    self.myVar = myVar
  # I am not going to make everything legitamite here

def compare(first, second):
  # I want to make first = the first object i am comparing
  # second = second object i am comparing
  # I would then use it in a conditional
```

This probably not the best way of going about this, and if there is a better way I would love to know.

Comment: So by object you mean `class instance` right ? So you want to compare any class instances ?

Comment: @Dax Loy: You want to use PM 2Ring answer's, it's arguably *the* way to go (see my comment to sshashank124's answer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to pass in 2 instances of a class and then compare their values. If so, you can simply do it as follows:

```
class tester:
  myVar = None
  def __init__(self, myVar):
    self.myVar = myVar

def compare(first, second):
  if first.myVar > second.myVar:
    return "First object has a greater value"
  elif first.myVar < second.myVar:
    return "Second object has a greater value"
  else:
   return "Both objects have the same value"

obj1 = tester(5)
obj2 = tester(7)

>>> print(compare(obj1, obj2))
#Output: Second object has a greater value
```

Comment: This is definitely not the best way to do this: it is not standard, it makes the calling code more complicated, and you cannot use functions like `max()`, `sort()`, etc. Python has `__cmp__()` just for this (see the answer by PM 2Ring).

Comment: @EOL, I understand. I was just trying to provide a simple example. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to do this is to define a `__cmp__()` method in your class. That way, you can use the standard comparison operators `< == != >`, etc, and the built-in [cmp()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) function on your class instances. Also, if an object defines `__cmp__()` it will behave properly when passed to functions like `max()` and `sort()`. (Thanks to EOL for reminding me to mention that).

Eg,

```
class tester(object):   
    def __init__(self, myVar):
        self.myVar = myVar

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.myVar, other.myVar)


print tester(5) < tester(7)
print tester(6) == tester(6)
print tester(9) > tester(6)
print tester('z') < tester('a')
print cmp(tester((1, 2)), tester((1, 3)))
```

**output**

```
True
True
True
False
-1
```

Note that I've made tester inherit from `object`, which makes it a [new-style class](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass). That's not strictly necessary, but it does have various benefits.

I've also removed the `myVar = None` class attribute, which as EOL points out in the comments is unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Why have a class attribute `myVar`?? I can't see how it could be useful.

Comment: I would add that another advantage of defining `__cmp__` is that the new class can be used anywhere an ordered type is needed (`max()`, `sort()`, etc.).

Comment: @EOL: Agreed. It's just an artifact of the code in the OP. I'll get rid of it.

Comment: @EOL: I still use Python 2.6.6. I only wrapped the `print` stuff in parentheses because I see it in a lot of code examples here, presumably so the code will run on Py2 and Py3, although it looks cluttered to me. :) Should I not do that in future?

Comment: If you use Python 2.6.6, `print …` without parentheses is definitely the standard usage (you can see that in the Python documentation, etc.). If you use Python 3, then `print(…)`, without any space, is the normal (function call) convention. If you port your code later for Python 3, `2to3` will take care of adding the parentheses for you, so there is no reason to put them already. The virtue of following standard practices is that it makes your code more legible for everybody. :)

Comment: @EOL: Ok. FWIW, I _never_ use the parentheses in my own code, only stuff I post here.